# Does there exist a type similar to std::string (i.e., holding blobs of data of arbitrary length) that does not use the null terminator?

Tags: c++, c++11

I use `std::string` to hold arbitrary blobs of binary data. It works this way, but is slightly inefficient as it needs to add the null terminator to the end of the blob. (C++11 spec is that `c_str()` and `data()` are the same, and return a pointer to a blob with a null terminator at the end.) Is there a better type to use, that still supports common operations (copy constructor, assignment operator, etc)?

Comment: The null-terminator makes it inefficient? What makes you think that? Maybe you would be happy with `std::vector` then?

Comment: why do you think null-termination has any cost? (not saying that it has zero, but I would be surprised if it has any measurable impact)

Comment: There's `std::vector<char>`, but it doesn't do short buffer optimization. Is it important for you?

Comment: `std::vector<char>`

Comment: Since it's *binary* data, you should use `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: or even `std::vector<std::byte>` in C++17

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector`. Documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job. A [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is designed to store and manipulate sequences of `char`-like objects. This incorporates a mechanism ([`std::char_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits)) to define text processing, which can be used to introduce more overhead than the terminating null character. As one example, the character traits could be used to sort strings case-insensitively. Blobs of binary data are not "text", so a string is not a great semantic fit for the job at hand.

The best fit for binary data is [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte), but that was not introduced until C++17, and this question is tagged C++11. The pre-17 options are `char` and `unsigned char` (and `std::uint8_t`, if that type is provided and if you don't need to do type aliasing); I would recommend the latter since signed types add semantics not applicable to raw binary data.

Once you've picked the basic unit for your data, you need to collect several of these units into a [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). When in doubt - when you have no particular reason to choose one container over another - use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), as that tends to perform well in many circumstances. (Not to mention that the functionality of a `std::string` is that of a `std::vector<char>` plus additional string functionality. You want to eliminate the overhead of the additional string functionality, right?)

```
std::vector<std::byte>      // C++17
std::vector<unsigned char>  // Earlier standards
```